# "Create A List Item" workflow into another list in another site or subsite in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to "Create a list item" into another list which is in another site / subsite. Using the workflow "Create a list item", the list I need does not show in the selection. Is there a way to do this in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: what is your workflow trigger? On item creation or item changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, you can call [HTTP Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822159.aspx) in SharePoint Designer workflows. but in Sharepoint 2010 based on my humble knowledge, there is no OOTB solution.

So you will need as a workaround to develop that by creating an event receiver on item added in the first list to add the list item to a specific list in a specific site.

Meanwhile, there are many solutions that require a license like **plumsail** that help you to [create a list Item at Any Site](https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/Actions/List%20items%20processing.html#create-list-item-at-any-site) via SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Thank you as usual M.Qassas! By the way are there any third party solutions that can do the same? We have Virto but I don't believe they have the workflow function.

Comment: you are welcome, regarding vitro I didn't use it before but I checked its features and not find this functionality at https://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint/workflow-activities-extensions-for-microsoft-sharepoint-designer#features meanwhile I have mentioned plumsail as a third party tool you can check its feature from the above-attached link in my answer